# XML and RDF for semantic web

Tags: xml, rdf

I am confused why RDF is suitable over XML for semantic web. For eg in RDF I have the following subject,predicate,object triplet

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about=“#York”>
    <tel>6086592</tel>
</rdf:Description>
```

I can write something similar in XML like

```
<person name="#York">
     <tel>6086592</tel>
</person>
```

So what's the point of using RDF. Need some clarifications?

Answer (score 0):

XML is just a syntax for data, RDF attempts to provide a framework for describing data.  With XML, its a convenient, machine readable format which you can validate the format of (DTD), transform (XSLT), or query (XPath).  But it attempts to provide no formal meaning to the data, that's up to whatever is reading it and it can differ from application to application.

One of the benefits of using RDF is you can attach a formal meaning to the data, using something like the standard RDF [model theory](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-mt/), [RDFS](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/), or very expressive semantics using any of the [OWL2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-primer/) profiles.

RDF can be represented as XML, but don't get hung up on that.  There's many syntaxes for RDF, most of which are more human friendly than RDF/XML, such as Turtle.  Represent the data however you like, the meaning stays the same.

You might find the [RDF primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/) a useful place to start learning more about RDF and what it can be used for.

Answer (score 0):

The point of RDF is that collections of RDF triples (interpretted in the context of some ontology for the predicates) are a *systematized* representation of knowledge.

By contrast, while XML can also be interpretted as knowledge, there is no framework that relates one set of XML documents and schemas to another.

Another difference is that RDF is an "open" information model ... in the sense that you can add new forms of knowledge (e.g. new predicate URLs) at will.  By contrast, XML is constrained by the explicit schema, or if there is none, by the ability of a tool to process a particular XML structure.  These tend to make an XML-based information model "closed".

You can trivially represent any collection of RDF triples as XML.  (Indeed your example does this!)  What sets RDF (+ OWL) apart from plain XML is that it is richer, and more flexible way of modelling information / knowledge.

(It is sort of like comparing assembly language versus Java.  They are computationally equivalent, but Java is more expressive, and consequently easier to use.)

Answer (score -1):

XML data model is a tree. 
RDF data model is a graph.

A tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one simple path.
You can represent graphs with XML, but not as easy and naturally as with RDF.